Synthesize 1-Acetyl-2-methylcyclopentene from cyclohexene
I have been assigned to synthesize 1-acetyl-2-methylcyclopentene using cyclohexene. I have figured out that once I have the 1-methyl-1-cyclopentene, I can finish the reaction but just using acetyl chloride and aluminum chloride.
But, when it comes to rearranging the cyclohexene to 1-methyl-cyclopentene (1-acetyl-2-methylcyclopentene!!!), I can’t figure out how to do it.

I doubt the AcCl/$\ce{AlCl3}$ works here. You might need to find a way to directly ring-contract an acylated form of your starting material.

Work this out. Ozonolysis, Grignard, oxidation, and aldol condensation.
